# Make font of user-typed text in the search boxes on the main and meta sites black

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, search, accessibility

Currently, the text is very light gray which makes it hard to read. Think it should be black.

[image]

Comment: I think this is a new bug? It used to only be the placeholder text that was grey if I'm remembering right, typed text was black

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreed. The color of the text is #AAAAAA. On a white background it doesn't pass WCAG AA compliance. Contrast ratio is far too low. See this screenshot taken from  [snook.ca](http://snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html)

[image]

It'll be much better at #545454 or even darker:

[image]

I've looked over a bunch of other StackExchange sites and none of the ones I checked have such a feint colour for the search field text.

Answer (score 4):

This has been fixed on dev server. The change will be on live after our next production build(within 24hours).

Comment: It works now! Thanks a lot!